# Python : Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I am receiving an unexpected syntax error from the following code. Whereas this code works fine when broken into individual parts.

```
Line_Point_1 = list(map(float,input("Point 1 :").split(" ")))

Line_Point_2 = list(map(float,input("Point 2 :").split(" ")))

Circle_Centre = list(map(float,input("Circle Centre :").split(" ")))
rad = float(input("Radius :"))

print(Line_Point_1[0],Line_Point_1[1],Line_Point_2[0],Line_Point_2[1],Circle_Centre[0],Circle_Centre[1],rad)
m = (Line_Point_2[1]-Line_Point_1[1])/(Line_Point_2[0]-Line_Point_1[0])
c1 = Line_Point_2[1]-(m*Line_Point_2[0])

a = (m**2)+1
b = (2.0*m*(c1-Circle_Centre[1])-(2.0*Circle_Centre[0])
c = ((Circle_Centre[0])**2)+((c1-Circle_Centre[1])**2)-(rad**2)

val = (b**2)-(4.0*a*c)

if(val == 0):
    print("Tangent")
elif(val > 0):
    print("Cuts the Cirle")
else:
    print("Doesn't Touch the Circle")
```

Can anyone help me and tell what is causing the error.

Comment: Post the next few lines above this one.  Sometimes, in python, failure to include a trailing parentheses on a line gives errors on following lines.  In other words, the real error may be above this.

Comment: You need to show the definitions for `Circle_Centre`, `c1`, and `rad`. When I define these variables, the line of code you show works fine for me.

Comment: These is the complete code.
Line_Point_1 = list(map(float,input("Point 1 :").split(" ")))
Line_Point_2 = list(map(float,input("Point 2 :").split(" ")))
Circle_Centre = list(map(float,input("Circle Centre :").split(" ")))
rad = float(input("Radius :"))

Comment: print(Line_Point_1[0],Line_Point_1[1],Line_Point_2[0],Line_Point_2[1],Circle_Centre[0],Circle_Centre[1],rad)
m = (Line_Point_2[1]-Line_Point_1[1])/(Line_Point_2[0]-Line_Point_1[0])
c1 = Line_Point_2[1]-(m*Line_Point_2[0])

a = (m**2)+1
b = (2.0*m*(c1-Circle_Centre[1])-(2.0*Circle_Centre[0])
c = ((Circle_Centre[0])**2)+((c1-Circle_Centre[1])**2)-(rad**2)

val = (b**2)-(4.0*a*c)

if(val == 0):
    print("Tangent")
elif(val > 0):
    print("Cuts the Cirle")
else:
    print("Doesn't Touch the Circle")

Comment: @NarendraMajhi, if you would like to post an answer for posterity with an lucid explanation of what the problem turned out to be, and how you ended up solving it, I will upvote it.

Comment: @Scott Actually, in the calculation of variable b, just above variable c. As you pointed out. I missed a closing bracket, which ended with generating the error in the codes.

Comment: @NarendraMajhi, here on Stack Overflow, anyone having a similar problem will look to the answers, not the comments for a solution.  Please, if you know the answer, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`(Circle_Centre[0])2` is not a valid Python syntax. Use `Circle_Centre[0]*2` if you mean to multiply `Circle_Centre[2]` by 2.

Comment: Hi, My code looks like this. ((Circle_Centre[0])**2)+((c1-Circle_Centre[1])**2)-(rad**2).
The above is a copy paste mistake.
Any views on this.